# Como puedo hacer el calculo de descuento con jquery

Tags: jquery

Quiero realizar el siguiente calculo:

El coste de este transporte serà de 50€ por día, y se hará un 20% de descuento en alquileres superiores a 10 días.

```js
$("#ccalc").click(function(){

            var dias_coche = $("#cnumber").val();
            
            
            var calculo_coche = 50 * dias_coche;

            if (dias_coche > 10){
               
                
             
            }
            console.log(calculo_coche);
```

Comment: qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es hacer el 20% a todos los días sí superan los 10 días sería algo así.

```
var dias_coche = 11;
var partida_descuento = 10;
var precio_dia = 50;
var descuento = 0.2;


if (dias_coche > partida_descuento){
    var calculo_coche = precio_dia * dias_coche - ((precio_dia * dias_coche)*descuento);
} else {
    var calculo_coche = precio_dia * dias_coche;
}
console.log(calculo_coche);

// 440
//Cada día sale a 40€
```

En cambio, si solo quieres descontar los días a partir de los 10 días.

```
var dias_coche = 11;
var partida_descuento = 10;
var precio_dia = 50;
var descuento = 0.2;


if (dias_coche > partida_descuento){

   var dias_con_descuento = dias_coche - partida_descuento ;
   var calculo_coche = (partida_descuento * precio_dia) + ((dias_con_descuento*precio_dia) - ((precio_dia * dias_con_descuento)*descuento));
} else {
   var calculo_coche = precio_dia * dias_coche;

}

console.log(calculo_coche);

// 540
// Los primeros 10 días salen a 50€ el día 11 sale a 40€
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Pues dentro de tu `if`

```
var desc_calculo = calculo_coche - (calculo_coche * .20);
```

Explicó:

Primero sacamos el `20%` del costo total por los días y después ese descuento se lo restas al total.
Si son 11  días por 50€ serían 550€, menos el 20% de 550€ que es 110€, el cliente estaría pagando 440€.

Espero te funcione

Comment: Sip, error fatal, ya la edite.

Answer (score 2):

### Una forma simple de hacerlo

Asumiendo que tienes una caja de texto denominada `cnumber`y un botón denominado `ccalc`se puede utilizar:

```js
ccalc.onclick = () => {
  // Obtiene el valor de la caja de texto:
  var diasCoche = cnumber.value;

  // El cálculo realizado:
  var calculoCoche = 50 * diasCoche;
  
  // Si es mayor a 10 días descontar 20%
  if ( diasCoche > 10 )
    console.log( calculoCoche, "20% de descuento =>", calculoCoche * 0.8 );
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="cnumber" id="cnumber">
<button id="ccalc">Calcular</button>
```

No se realizan validaciones porque se asume que lo que se quiere es entender cómo realizar el cálculo en función de si es mayor a 10 días.

Obviando todo el código JavaScript, el cálculo simple sería:

```js
calculoCoche * 0.8
```

Donde `calculoCoche` se multiplica por `0.8` para obtener el `20%` de descuento.

Por lo tanto, la forma más simple de hacerlo es ésta:

```js
if ( diasCoche > 10 ) {
  calculoCoche *= 0.8; // Se descuenta 20%.
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón. Tuve que corregir el código. El problema fue que lo pensé a la inversa, es decir, que si tienes un `numero` multiplicado por `1.2` le agregas el `20%`, mientras que al `resultado` lo divides por `1.2` vuelve a ser el número anterior. Es una operación matemática válida, pero no para ese contexto. De allí el error.

Comment: En matemáticas, cuando divides un número por `1.2` lo haces sobre la base del número que originó al número que está siendo divido por el valor antes mencionado. Pero en este caso, `calculoCoche` no es un número que haya sido originado sobre la base de un 20% agregado ya que él es el número base sobre el que se tiene que realizar el cálculo.

Comment: En tu caso en vez de calcular el `20%` que se va a descontar estas calculando directamente el `80%` restante lo digo por (_para obtener el 20% de descuento_). Lo cual está bien y es otra manera de verlo, pero no creo que se deba realizar la resta (por muy simple que sea) a ojo. `calculoCoche *= 1-0.2;`